# Each row from PHP odbc_fetch_row takes longer to query

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

Background:
We have some PHP code on a windows server set up with a ODBC connection to an MS Access file.
On one table, while calling odbc_fetch_row, each row takes longer to query. Here is my output of the time:

Each line represents a row in the DB:

1.735685 Seconds
1.811737 Seconds
1.883636 Seconds
1.958602 Seconds
2.033057 Seconds
2.103798 Seconds

Some sample code of connection and loop:

```
$accessDB = odbc_connect('ACCESS_DB','','',SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
$result = odbc_exec($accessDB,$sql);

while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
    {
        if($testCount > 1000) break;

        printTimer();

            $testCount++;
        }
```

I can't figure out why it's doing this, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that  `printTimer()` resets the timer to zero before it returns? If you look at the *differences* between each value they are fairly consistent, ranging from 0.076 to 0.071 seconds.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't restart but for some reason it takes a really long time to loop the Access file. I can't find a lot of details on this? Any Ideas